# Pythonic way of Adding Columns to Array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to combine an **m**x**n** array called *data* with a list of **m** elements called *cluster_data* such that each element in the list *cluster_data* is appended as the last element of each of the rows in *data*.

As an example, I would want something like to combine

```
data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]

cluster_data = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Such that

```
final_data = [[1,2,3,4,1],[5,6,7,8,2],[9,10,11,12,3],[13,14,15,16,4],[17,18,19,20,5]]
```

I have written some code that does this, but I was hoping for a more Pythonic way.

```
data_with_clusters = []    
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    row.append(cluster_data[i])
    data_with_clusters.append(row)
```

My best guess so far, which doesn't work, is:

```
data_with_clusters = [row.append(cluster_data[i]) for i, row in enumerate(data)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the most pythonic way

`final_data = [i+[j] for i,j in zip(data, cluster_data)]`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that `append` doesn't return anything.

Instead of append, merge lists:

```
[row + [cluster_data[i]] for i, row in enumerate(data)]
```

or

```
[e[0] + [e[1]] for e in zip(data, cluster_data)]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I used the first one. Can you explain why you need brackets around cluster_data[i]?

Comment: The `+` operator in this case merges two *lists*.

Comment: Please accept Yash's solution, it's really the most pythonic one.

Answer (score 2):

A Pythonic way would be to use [Array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) first thing first. Lists are commonly abused as `array`, because they share some similarity.

But a more Pythonic way, if you often work with numbers is to use NumPy. Which makes such operations a piece of cake.

The answers with list comprehension given previously are fine too, but  they will be extremely slow for large arrays.

Here is your intro to NumPy:

```
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: array = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]])

In [3]: array
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20]])

In [4]: col = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
In [4]: col
Out[4]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])

In [5]: np.append(array, col, axis=1)
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  1],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12,  3],
       [13, 14, 15, 16,  4],
       [17, 18, 19, 20,  5]])
```

Comment: Also if you are crunching many numbers with python you should get familiar with IPython, which the code snippets in my answer are from

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. About IPython and NumPy in particular. I was not aware that NumPy was so much more convenient!

Comment: Numpy is defacto the standard for working with array and matrix. If you do a lot of number crunching, take a look into scipy and pandas too.

Answer (score 1):

`row.append(cluster_data[i])` returns None, so that doesn't work,

Try instead: `row + [cluster_data[i]]`